# Как последовательно переставить символы в строке, из нулевого индекса на последний

Tags: javascript

```
[ 'ROBOT', // с начала входное слово
  'OBOTR', // Потом с переставленым порядком символов
  'BOTRO',
  'OTROB',
  'TROBO' ]


    function scrollingText(word) {
  let upperCase = word.toUpperCase()
  resArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < upperCase.length; i++) {
    resArray.push(upperCase[i]);
    console.log('Original', resArray);
    let newLetterArray = resArray.slice(upperCase[i]);
   
    console.log('New', newLetterArray)
  }
  return 'final result' + ' ' + resArray
}
let res = scrollingText('Tymoha');
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Конкатенируем две копии слова. Потом берём подстроку, начиная с первого символа, со второго, с третьего...

Comment: Не знаю как записать(

Comment: Можете пожалуйста привести пример? я вообще не могу понять эту задачу.